# Google Script App deploy only for one person

Tags: google-apps-script

I got a little bit stuck right now at deploying my Google Script App.
I've developed a Google Script App, which is embedded directly into
Google Drive (Spreadsheet). It's not a Web App, it's a user interface
in Google Spreadsheet (sorry, but i have to be clear).

That Script is just for one person in another company.

How can i deploy my script to her?

I've read about Domain-Wide-Installation and publishing an App to the marketplace, but i want to deploy it just for her and no one else.

How can i achieve that?

Thanks
Best regards

Comment: Do you care if the person can see the code or not?  Do you want the code to be inaccessible?  Does the code need to run under your permissions even though someone else is using it?  For example, is the code only accessing files owned by the other person, or does the code access any files owned by you?

Comment: First thanks for your fast comment. I want the code to be inaccessible, so the user can't see the code. The code should run under the persons permissions and for the files owned by the person.

Comment: You can publish an Add-on as "unlisted", which means that it can not be seen in the Chrome Store, and does not need to go through the approval process.  When an add-on is installed, it has the authority to check the users email address.  So, you could set it up so that it could only be installed by this person.  An Add-on will keep the code from being accessible to anyone.  Although you might want to also use private functions.  I don't know if there is a better way for the Domain Administrator in a paid account to do what you want.  I don't know anything about that.

Comment: "You can publish an Add-on as "unlisted", which means that it can not be seen in the Chrome Store, and does not need to go through the approval process." That's exactly what i want. Is there a walkaround for publishing an Add-on as unlisted? Does the Domain Administrator have to publish the Add-on for the user or can i publish it?

Comment: You'll need to pay a $5 U.S. one time fee first.  Even though it's unlisted and doesn't need to be approved, you will need to add some graphics files.  Anything will do as long as they are the correct dimensions.  After publishing, you can get the URL link, and email it to the person you want to have install it.  The Add-on will show up in the list of published items.  You might want to consider joining the Add-on group: [Link to Google Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494)

Comment: Sorry i have to ask: if i get you correctly, then i have to create a G-Suite account, publish the app, send the link to the person, and that's it? It works although my domain (from g-suite) is different than the companys domain? Thanks for the link to the community. I definitly will join.

Comment: I don't know anything about the G-Suite account.

Comment: Ok, i deployed the app as "unlisted" from my account and installed it from another account with the link. Worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big thanks to Sandy Good.

"You can publish an Add-on as "unlisted", which means that it can not be seen in the Chrome Store, and does not need to go through the approval process. When an add-on is installed, it has the authority to check the users email address. So, you could set it up so that it could only be installed by this person. An Add-on will keep the code from being accessible to anyone. Although you might want to also use private functions. I don't know if there is a better way for the Domain Administrator in a paid account to do what you want. I don't know anything about that." - Sandy Good.

That was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An add-on can also published for testers. Those testers must be part of a google group. Maintaining a group is easier.